# Java Frame Disappears when trying to pop up a message box?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, messagebox

I have a java code that responds to a button click event. The Parent JFrame which has the button Disappears when i try to pop up a message box , So what's the problem ?

Here are the codes :

```
private void TestConnectionButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     

    InitDatabaseObject();

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            if(Database.ConnectToDatabase())
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection succeeded");

            }else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection failed");
            }
        }
    }); 



    Database.CloseDbConnection();

}
```

Help me plz ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection succeeded");
```

try to use reference to your JFrame (which you don't want to disappear) instead of null

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Connection succeeded");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dialog is not "attached" to the JFrame. Change your code to

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jframe,"Connection succeeded");
```

where jframe is a reference to your JFrame object.